# tkinter: make a scrollable canvas react to item deletion

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to make a reactive scrollable list of items.

currently I have a canvas, scrollbar and item container defined as follows:

```py
        self.scroll_bar = tk.Scrollbar(self.container, orient=tk.VERTICAL)
        self.scroll_bar.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.Y)

        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self.container, yscrollcommand=self.scroll_bar.set)
        self.canvas.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)
        self.scroll_bar.config(command=self.canvas.yview)

        self.item_container = tk.Frame(self.canvas)
        self.canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=self.item_container, anchor=tk.NW)
```

when items (`tk.Frame`s) are added or removed from `item_container` it calls the update_canvas_scroll_region method:

```py
    def update_canvas_scrollregion(self):
        self.item_container.update_idletasks()
        self.canvas.config(scrollregion=self.canvas.bbox("all"))
```

this works fine for adding items but doesn't update properly when items are removed, I think its because the `canvas.bbox("all")` doesn't shrink to fit when items are deleted.

full code: https://github.com/harrisabdullah/tk_scrollable_list

Comment: No, the issue is not `canvas.bbox('all')`. The problem is that when you delete the `image` or `frame` with `ImageEditUI.delete()` there is no link with `ScrollableList.delete_item()` and thus the scrollable region does not get adjusted.

Comment: If you print child after deleting, you will see that they were not deleted. Probably because of the references to them from the class. I managed to delete them by name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took the liberty to change the class `ImageEditUI` into `ImageFrame` as that is what the class is doing, it makes a frame containing the image, input field and a delete button.
The `ScrollableList` is the main UI and in order to make the link with `ImageFrame` it creates the instance in the `__init__` (`self.image_frame = ImageFrame()`).

To make the link with the delete button (made in `ImageFrame`) bind this button to the function `delete_item` of `ScrollableList` and pass this function the newly created `image_frame`. Deleting the frame is done by a call to `ImageFrame.delete_item`

A working example is shown below.

```
from functools import partial
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk


class ScrollableList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.item_container = None
        self.canvas = None
        self.scroll_bar = None
        self.container = None
        self.image_frame = ImageFrame()

    def start(self, root):
        self.container = tk.Frame(root)
        self.container.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

        self.scroll_bar = tk.Scrollbar(self.container, orient=tk.VERTICAL)
        self.scroll_bar.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.Y)

        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self.container, yscrollcommand=self.scroll_bar.set)
        self.canvas.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)
        self.scroll_bar.config(command=self.canvas.yview)

        self.item_container = tk.Frame(self.canvas)
        self.canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=self.item_container, anchor=tk.NW)
        self.canvas.bind_all("<MouseWheel>", self.on_mousewheel)

    def update_canvas_scrollregion(self):
        self.item_container.update_idletasks()
        self.canvas.config(scrollregion=self.canvas.bbox("all"))

    def on_mousewheel(self, event):
        self.canvas.yview_scroll(event.delta, "units")

    def add_item(self, image_path):
        image_frame, delete_button = self.image_frame.add_item(
            self.item_container, image_path
        )
        # link the delete button from the image_frame to the delete_item function of ImageContainer
        delete_button.configure(
            command=partial(self.delete_item, image_frame=image_frame)
        )
        self.update_canvas_scrollregion()

    def delete_item(self, image_frame):
        self.image_frame.delete_item(image_frame)
        self.update_canvas_scrollregion()


class ImageFrame:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def add_item(self, container, image_path):
        PIL_image = Image.open(image_path)
        PIL_image.thumbnail((800, 800))
        image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(PIL_image)
        image_frame = tk.Frame(container)
        image_frame.pack()

        image_label = tk.Label(image_frame, image=image)
        image_label.image = image
        image_label.pack(padx=5, pady=5)

        label = tk.Label(image_frame, text="entre words in image: ")
        label.pack()

        input = tk.Entry(image_frame, width=50)
        input.pack()

        delete_button = tk.Button(image_frame, text="Delete")
        delete_button.pack()

        return image_frame, delete_button

    def delete_item(self, container):
        for child in container.winfo_children():
            child.destroy()
        container.destroy()

    def export(self):
        pass


def main():
    scrollable_list = ScrollableList()
    root = tk.Tk()
    scrollable_list.start(root)
    scrollable_list.add_item("pic3.jpg")
    scrollable_list.add_item("pic4.jpg")
    scrollable_list.add_item("pic5.jpg")
    scrollable_list.add_item("pic6.jpg")
    root.mainloop()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: One suggestion instead of have a method `start`, I would move all this to the `__init__(self, root)`. Then start the app by calling `scrollable_list = ScrollableList(root)` in `main`.